# .Net Threading Bidirectional

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a C# windows forms application.
The application has a single windows form.
I would like a button click event on the form to kick off a worker thread that manages a third party library.

I also have a C# asp.net web application.
The application has a single web page (for the purpose of this question).
I would like a button click on the web page to kick off a worker thread that manages the same third party library.

My worker thread does the following
1. Sets a callback function on the third party library so it can call me back when certain events occur
2. Initiates an operation (not async) in the third party library (that will ultimately call my callback).

I would like the callback (my callback called by the third party library) to send a message to the UI (whether windows forms or web).

I cannot exit the stack frame in which my callback is running, so I need the callback to notify another thread that the callback
requires data.  That other thread can then determine whether it wants to callback to the windows UI or to the web client (for this
question, I am not interested in how to callback to the web client)

When the UI receives the message, I would like the UI to display a dialog asking the user for information.  Once the user has answered
the questions and dismissed the dialog, I would like the data captured in the dialog to be returned to the callback function (which was
waiting, since it cannot progress without the data).

Both the web UI and the windows form UI can be waiting as well, though my preference is they would not be, and I would handle the
requests from the worker thread in an independent portion of the user interface that remains visible regardless of what other work
the user might be doing.

So, the basic architecture looks like this.
[image: Architecture]

Given the current feature set of C# as of 2016, what is the best way to accomplish this task?

Bascially, I require two-way communication between threads, and I need to ensure I don't violate the SynchronizationContext (in the winforms case).

I have viewed a number of answers, some using Progress. None of the answers show the callback waiting for an answer from the UI, and the UI handling multiple callbacks. I could fashion this using old style threading primitives, but I would like to use Task, and maybe async/await. This is surely a common pattern, but I could not seem to find it.  What is the present day best practice for having a background thread callback to a UI thread, having the UI thread display something, collect a result, and then return that result to the background thread?

Comment: What is the role of the intermediary thread? As I understand, the callback has to wait for response anyway.